# I am getting error during installation at 73% for 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email' saying invalid column email

Tags: magento2, installation

```
Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email':
Installing data... Upgrading data...
[ERROR] PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'imported' in 'where clause' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php:91 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(91): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(107): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\{closure}() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(92): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->tryExecute(Object(Closure)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `email_c...', Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(546): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `email_c...', Array) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(613): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('UPDATE `email_c...', Array) #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor.php(128): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('UPDATE `email_c...', Array) #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(635): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->query('UPDATE `email_c...', Array) #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor.php(1519): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('email_catalog', Array, '(imported) AND ...') #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\dotmailer\dotmailer-magento2-extension\Setup\UpgradeData.php(239): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->update('email_catalog', Array, Array) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\dotmailer\dotmailer-magento2-extension\Setup\UpgradeData.php(132): Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Setup\UpgradeData->upgradeFourOhOne(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext)) #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(992): Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Setup\UpgradeData->upgrade(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext)) #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(879): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data', Array) #15 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array) #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(368): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #19 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #20 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #21 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #22 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #23 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #24 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #25 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #26 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #27 {main} Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'imported' in 'where clause', query was: UPDATE `email_catalog` SET `processed` = ? WHERE (imported) AND (modified IS NULL OR modified = 0) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php:110 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(92): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->tryExecute(Object(Closure)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `email_c...', Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(546): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `email_c...', Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(613): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('UPDATE `email_c...', Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor.php(128): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('UPDATE `email_c...', Array) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(635): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->query('UPDATE `email_c...', Array) #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor.php(1519): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('email_catalog', Array, '(imported) AND ...') #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\dotmailer\dotmailer-magento2-extension\Setup\UpgradeData.php(239): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->update('email_catalog', Array, Array) #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\dotmailer\dotmailer-magento2-extension\Setup\UpgradeData.php(132): Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Setup\UpgradeData->upgradeFourOhOne(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext)) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(992): Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Setup\UpgradeData->upgrade(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext)) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(879): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data', Array) #13 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array) #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(368): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #19 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #20 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #21 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #22 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #23 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #24 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #25 {main}
```

Comment: What version of Magento are you trying to install - 2.3.4?

Answer (score 0):

if you are installing Magento 2 creating a new project plaese disable this module.

- try to disable the module:

  php bin/magento module:disable Dotdigitalgroup_Email
- install magento 2
- enable module with:

  bin/magento module:enable Dotdigitalgroup_Email
- `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

often, the writer of modules forgets to insert the dependencies and upon a new installation the modules execute processes before the real matches are created in the database.

Cheers